# How to use http.get instead of http.jsonp in KendoUI Grid for Angular Project

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jsonp, angular-httpclient

I am trying to use get 'get' request but I am unable to do because the kendo UI grid with external form is using JSONP

Kendo UI Code:-

```
private fetch(action: string = '', data?: any): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http
     .jsonp(`https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products/${action}?${this.serializeModels(data)}`, 'callback')
     .pipe(map(res => <any[]>res));
}
```

I want to use this:-

```
private fetch(action: string = '', data?: any): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http
     .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${action}?${this.serializeModels(data)}`,  httpOptions)
     .pipe(map(res => <any[]>res));
}
```

It gives me error

Comment: Are you using Kendo UI or Keno UI for Angular?

Kendo UI uses jQuery.
Kendo UI for Angular is the Angular implementation.

Comment: @KeenanDiggs , I am using kendo UI for angular, I am stuck with https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/external-editing/ 
in this example they uses jsonp but I googled but din't find anything useful their , I need to populate my json data like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts this along with its httpHeaders.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the specific error you recieve.

Comment: @KeenanDiggs , I am using this. please check https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/external-editing/